# Access observables in other javascript outside of model with knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

So I have a view model like so:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.chartSeries = ko.observableArray(['All Series']);
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());

$(function (){
//I want to access it here
}
```

How do I accomplish this?

when I try `viewModel().chartSeries`, `viewModel.chartSeries` , `viewModel.chartSeries()`  etc. I get undefined errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting undefined errors because you don't have an instance of the view model in scope.  The easiest thing would be to do:

```
var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

$(function (){
  // do stuff with vm
  vm.chartSeries.push('Series A');
}
```

Comment: Hi John - that worked in that I can call it - but if the observable changes, it isn't reflected in the external function. Any idea how I can make it subscribe to it?

Comment: You can explicitly subscribe to observables, and the callback function will be called when the observable changes.  Read the documentation here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html. (search for: Explicitly subscribing)

What exactly are you trying to do?